# In R: sort data frame with non-unique values using custom vectors

Tags: r, sorting, dataframe, match

If given this data frame:

```
df <- 
  data.frame(
    v1=c("a","b","c","a"),
    v2=c("z", "x", "x", "y"),
    v3=c(1,2,3,4),
    v4=factor(c("id1", "id2", "id3", "id4")))

> df
  v1 v2 v3  v4
1  a  z  1 id1
2  b  x  2 id2
3  c  x  3 id3
4  a  y  4 id4
```

You can sort the data after `v1` with

```
df[order(df$v1),]
  v1 v2 v3  v4
1  a  z  1 id1
4  a  y  4 id4
2  b  x  2 id2
3  c  x  3 id3
```

And by a primary (`v1`) and secondary (`v2`) (to settle ties):

```
df[order(df$v1, df$v2),]
  v1 v2 v3  v4
4  a  y  4 id4
1  a  z  1 id1
2  b  x  2 id2
3  c  x  3 id3
```

If you want to sort by a custom - not alphabetically or numerically - vector `s` I only know to use match() and this only works when theres only unique values:

require(dplyr)

```
s <- c("b","c","a")
df %>%
  distinct(v1) %>%
  .[match(s,df$v1),]

  v1 v2 v3  v4
2  b  x  2 id2
3  c  x  3 id3
1  a  z  1 id1
```

So my question:

How can you 1) sort a data frame with not-unique values by a custom vector like `s`, and 2) how to include a secondary sort vector for instance to settle ties?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can order the match results:

```
df[order(match( df$v1, s), df$v2),]

#   v1 v2 v3  v4
# 2  b  x  2 id2
# 3  c  x  3 id3
# 4  a  y  4 id4
# 1  a  z  1 id1
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I have been looking for. It also handles a second level custom sort vector, like t <- c("z", "x", "y"): df[order(match(df$v1, s), match(df$v2, t)),].